# Beamer section numbers

Tags: beamer, pandoc

The default Pandoc template (2.04) puts the following in its LaTeX output with Beamer, and equivalents for parts and subsections.

```
\AtBeginSection{
\let\insertsectionnumber\relax
\let\sectionname\relax
\frame{\sectionpage}
}
```

This used to result in a frame with just the section. But, with Beamer 3.45, a number is printed too.

Is this a result of a change to how Beamer works?

What would be the best thing to add to Pandoc's templates to give the desired behaviour? Which is, just the title of the part/section/subsection and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In beamer version 3.45 the section page no longer uses `\insertsectionnumber` (see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/bde1770c3b71bd4ca932d7d9e8b485d7ab280328), so your first redefinition does not have any effect.

This has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/43e7df05e0ed8db7c3f94a985c70fce49c826b3c

A workaround could be to redefine the section page template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
    \frame{\sectionpage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
  \begingroup
    \centering
%    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}\sectionname~\thesection}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\section{sd}    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```